# Python Script - Email Parser

Tags: python

Good morning everyone,

I am taking a Python class right now and we havent covered what I am about to ask. So any help would be great. I have a Python Script that parses emails out of document, but it only allows me to do one document at a time. I have roughly 500 gigs of documents and most of them contain email addresses. I was wondering if there is a way to change this script to read all subfolders and documents and skip over any errors if there are any. I understand there are some file types it may not be able to read. Some of the common file types are .txt, .csv, .sql, .xlsx.

Here is the script I found and it works very well for one file at a time. As always thanks everyone for the help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Extracts email addresses from one or more plain text files.
#
# Notes:
# - Does not save to file (pipe the output to a file if you want it saved).
# - Does not check for duplicates (which can easily be done in the terminal).
#


from optparse import OptionParser
import os.path
import re

regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
                    "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
                    "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

def file_to_str(filename):
    """Returns the contents of filename as a string."""
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().lower() # Case is lowered to prevent regex mismatches.

def get_emails(s):
    """Returns an iterator of matched emails found in string s."""
    # Removing lines that start with '//' because the regular expression
    # mistakenly matches patterns like 'http://foo@bar.com' as '//foo@bar.com'.
    return (email[0] for email in re.findall(regex, s) if not email[0].startswith('//'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: python %prog [FILE]...")
    # No options added yet. Add them here if you ever need them.
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args:
        parser.print_usage()
        exit(1)

    for arg in args:
        if os.path.isfile(arg):
            for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                print email
        else:
            print '"{}" is not a file.'.format(arg)
            parser.print_usage()
```

Comment: Well, you could call that script from another one that navigates subfoldes, so you would have one process per document (it would have the benefit of not making your code stop on parsing errors and you would process multiple documents at once). I'd also recommend to add a list of supported file types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `os.walk` like this:

```
not_parseble_files = ['.txt', '.csv']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):#This recursively searches all sub directories for files
    for file in files:
        _,file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)#Here we get the extension of the file
        file_path = os.path.join(root,file)
        if file_ext in not_parseble_files:#We make sure the extension is not in the banned list 'not_parseble_files'
           print("File %s is not parseble"%file_path)
           continue #This one continues the loop to the next file
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            for email in get_emails(file_to_str(file_path)):
                print(email)
```

Comment: Thank you.I will give this a shot.

Comment: As an input to the script you will now have to give the root directory of the subfolders

Comment: File "parser.py", line 38
    print "File %s is not parseble"%file_path
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("File %s is not parseble"%file_path)?

-- That is the message I get

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am using python 2.7. You have to use the parentehses, I updated my answer

Comment: I get errors with this too. 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Documents/parser.py", line 32, in <module>
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):#This recursively searches all sub directories for files
NameError: name 'root_folder' is not defined`
@alexandru-martalogu thank you for the help.

Comment: You have to assign args, which I belive to be the folder path you are giving as input, to root_folder

Comment: so `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder)` that root_folder needs to be like  `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(D:\Documents\)`? Again thanks for sticking with me. I cant wait to be a wizard in python like yourself.

Comment: Yes that is correct! Not a wizard, wish I was. Merely a lot of practice and debugs. Anyways, "Accio bug" ;)

Comment: I just wanted you to know I got it working so far. I get some errors where it says it cant read a file but I am going to find a way for it to skip errors.

Comment: `File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 5612: character maps to <undefined>` Thats the error I get.

Comment: I figured it out I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.walk` to traverse all the subdirectories:

```
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: python %prog [DIRECTORIES]...")
    # No options added yet. Add them here if you ever need them.
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args:
        parser.print_usage()
        exit(1)

    for dir in args:
        for root, _, files in os.walk(dir):
            for file in files:
                if any(file.endswith(ext) for ext in ('.txt', '.csv', '.sql', '.xlsx')):
                    for email in get_emails(file_to_str(os.path.join(root, file))):
                        print(email)
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a shot.

Comment: So I just replace with what you wrote?

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: python %prog [FILE]...")
         # No options added yet. Add them here if you ever need them.
         options, args = parser.parse_args()
    
        if not args:
            parser.print_usage()
            exit(1)
    
        for arg in args:
            if os.path.isfile(arg):
                for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                 print email
       else:
           print '"{}" is not a file.'.format(arg)
          parser.print_usage()

Comment: Yes the code in my answer is meant as a replacement to your main block.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will give this a shot.

Comment: So when I tried this I get a error message.
I run python parser.py \documents (because thats where all the folders are) > Master.txt
and I get this error
  File "parser.py", line 46
    print email(email)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This is because you're using Python 3.x, where `print` has become a function, not a statement. I've updated my answer so that `print` is called as a function.

Comment: I got a error @blhsing and again thank you for the help  

[Pastebin Error Code](https://pastebin.com/nyiSEY3j) 

https://pastebin.com/nyiSEY3j